# AWS Codepipeline with Github Version 1

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-codepipeline

I want to create a Codepipeline in AWS with Terraform that uses Github Version 1 (Using AWS Codestar is not really a solution). Is it still possible and if yes how?
I've tried creating a piepline but I get the following error message:

`Error creating CodePipeline: InvalidActionDeclarationException: ActionType (Category: 'Source', Provider: 'Github', Owner: 'ThirdParty', Version: '1') in action 'Source' is not available in region EU_CENTRAL_1`

Edit : Pipeline code

```
resource "aws_codepipeline" "ecs_pipeline" {
 ...
  stage {
    name = "Source"
    action {
      name             = "Source"
      category         = "Source"
      owner            = "ThirdParty"
      provider         = "Github"
      version          = 1
      run_order        = 1
      output_artifacts = ["SourceArtifact"]
      configuration = {

        RepositoryName       = var.repo_name
        BranchName           = var.branch
        OAuthToken           = var.github_oauth_token
        Owner                = var.repo_owner
      }
    }
  }
  stage {
    name = "Build"
    ...
  }
  stage {
    name = "Deploy"
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Without the code you are using, there is not much anyone can tell you so please add it to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, some configuration variable names were wrong

```
stage {
    name = "Source"
    action {
      name             = "Source"
      category         = "Source"
      owner            = "ThirdParty"
      provider         = "GitHub"
      version          = 1
      run_order        = 1
      output_artifacts = ["SourceArtifact"]
      configuration = {
        Repo             = var.repo_name
        Branch           = var.branch
        OAuthToken       = var.github_oauth_token
        Owner            = var.repo_owner
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: This helped, make sure you check the case sensitivity and spelling of the variables.  I had a similar issue and spent two hours on it only to find out spelled one of the variables with a different case.

Comment: where did you locate the `github_oauth_token`? Is that pulled from github?